# Best practise regarding static context

Tags: java, static, non-static

When writing a standalone java application, I see a lot of beginners code in the static context.
I used to get around this problem by creating an instance of the class in main, and working from the constructor.

I've added a few examples of a very simple standalone program, and would like to know if there are best practises for "leaving" the static context.

I would also like to know if there are things a standalone java program should be doing in the static context or specifically in the main method, what it's function is besides being the entry point of every standalone java program.

Any reading material is also welcome!

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ExampleStatic
{
    JLabel label;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Option 1 - Work from static context:
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(10,10,100,100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel staticlabel = new JLabel("static");
        frame.add(staticlabel);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Option 2 - Create instance, call initialisation function
        ExampleStatic e = new ExampleStatic();
        e.initialise();

        //Option 3 - Create instance, handle initialisation in constructor
        new ExampleStatic(true);
    }

    public ExampleStatic(){}

    public ExampleStatic(boolean init)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(10,10,100,100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        label = new JLabel("constructor");
        frame.add(label);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initialise()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(10,10,100,100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        label = new JLabel("init function");
        frame.add(label);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 2 and Option 3 both are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 and Option 3 both are fine, as both provide the loose coupling as well if you want to use your instance somewhere else in other classes you can use it easily. But if everything you will write in Main method you are going to loose the scope and its reusability.

Comment: I know this, but I would like to know if there are also things you should be doing in the static context, and not in a constructor or instance object function.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM needs `main` to be static, after that you're free to do what you want. I would call a non-static "second main" that would handle initialization and then any further processing in different methods (or classes).

I would avoid putting things in the constructor, unless you really feel it's the right place for them.

Comment: Do you mean the static main has no function besides being the entry point, and the Best Practise is to leave this as soon as possible?

Comment: You don't have to leave it if you don't want to. It's static because of the JVM, not the programmer.